# What does it mean when: The gods raised Valinor & globed the world?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

What does it mean when: The gods raised Valinor & globed the world? Does this mean that Valinor was raised high up in the sky above clouds & the air we breathe?

Comment: Why close votes? Is the quote inaccurate? If it is, it's a completely legit question.

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I did downvote. AFAICT it's not a quote from anywhere in particular, and the subject has been covered better in other questions (for example [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20300/what-are-the-undying-lands).)

Answer (score 20):

This refers to the [Changing of the World](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Changing_of_the_World):

> The Changing of the World was the event in which Arda was transformed
>   from a flat world into a round planet. It occurred near the end of the
>   Second Age when Eru destroyed the island of Númenor due to the deeds
>   of its people.
>
> When the Númenórean King Ar-Pharazôn attacked Valinor, the Valar
>   relinquished their dominion over Arda and called upon Eru for help.
>   Eru responded by creating an enormous rift between Númenor and the
>   Blessed Realm, into which Ar-Pharazôn's fleet and, ultimately, his
>   land were swept. Meanwhile, the flat world bent back upon itself and
>   met at this rift. The final result was a round planet of which Aman
>   and Tol Eressëa were no longer a physical part. After the Changing of
>   the World, only the Elves could find the Straight Way and reach the
>   ancient West by ship.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the gods separated their home from the mortal world and then shaped the world into its current, spherical, shape.

Comment: -1: The Valar are not gods, and it was not they who changed the world.

Comment: Yes they actually are gods. They are basically mini gods created by Eru Ilúvatar. Im not completely positive it was them who globed the world but since that wasnt the question it doesn't matter that much. But given the fact you've been wrong in your accusations so far i'm going out on a limb and saying your wrong about them not being the one's who globed Arda.

Comment: sorry, but you're demonstrating clearly that you know absolutely nothing about the subject matter and are basically making things up.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Maybe don't be so condescending about something that [isn't nearly as clear-cut](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/72150/20221) as you're making it out to be.